# Adding text to my stacked barchard with MatPlotLib (Python)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I got stuck on the way to place vertically text within my bars. 
My plot looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/pTcElMq.jpg?1
My intention is to place the text of the codons into the middle of each bar.
I've searched all over the internet without any solutions.

Someone got an idea for this issue?

My Python code looks like the following:

```
def Graph_Codons(Codons):
print(Codons)
N = 21
X = [Codons["TTA"],Codons["TCT"],Codons["CGT"],Codons["GGT"],Codons["GTT"],
     Codons["CCT"],Codons["ACT"],Codons["GCT"],Codons["ATT"],Codons["TTT"],
     Codons["TAT"],Codons["CAT"],Codons["CAA"],Codons["AAT"],Codons["AAA"],
     Codons["GAT"],Codons["GAA"],Codons["TGT"],Codons["TGG"],Codons["TAA"],
     Codons["ATG"]]
X1 = [Codons["TTG"],Codons["TCC"],Codons["CGC"],Codons["GGC"],Codons["GTC"],
      Codons["CCC"],Codons["ACC"],Codons["GCC"],Codons["ATC"],Codons["TTC"],
      Codons["TAC"],Codons["CAC"],Codons["CAG"],Codons["AAC"],Codons["AAG"],
      Codons["GAC"],Codons["GAG"],Codons["TGC"],0,Codons["TAG"],0]
X2 = [Codons["CTT"],Codons["TCA"],Codons["CGA"],Codons["GGA"],Codons["GTA"],
      Codons["CCA"],Codons["ACA"],Codons["GCA"],Codons["ATA"],0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
      0,0,0,Codons["TGA"],0] 
X3 = [Codons["CTC"],Codons["TCG"],Codons["CGG"],Codons["GGG"],Codons["GTG"],
      Codons["CCG"],Codons["ACG"],Codons["GCG"],0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
X4 = [Codons["CTA"],Codons["AGT"],Codons["AGA"],0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]    
X5 = [Codons["CTG"],Codons["AGC"],Codons["AGG"],0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

BotX2 = [X[0]+X1[0],X[1]+X1[1],X[2]+X1[2],X[3]+X1[3],X[4]+X1[4],X[5]+X1[5],
         X[6]+X1[6],X[7]+X1[7],X[8]+X1[8],X[9]+X1[9],X[10]+X1[10],X[11]+X1[11],
         X[12]+X1[12],X[13]+X1[13],X[14]+X1[14],X[15]+X1[15],X[16]+X1[16],
         X[17]+X1[17],X[18]+X1[18],X[19]+X1[19],X[20]+X1[20]]
BotX3 = [BotX2[0]+X2[0],BotX2[1]+X2[1],BotX2[2]+X2[2],BotX2[3]+X2[3],BotX2[4]+X2[4],
         BotX2[5]+X2[5],BotX2[6]+X2[6],BotX2[7]+X2[7],BotX2[8]+X2[8],BotX2[9]+X2[9],
         BotX2[10]+X2[10],BotX2[11]+X2[11],BotX2[12]+X2[12],BotX2[13]+X2[13],BotX2[14]+X2[14],
         BotX2[15]+X2[15],BotX2[16]+X2[16],BotX2[17]+X2[17],BotX2[18]+X2[18],BotX2[19]+X2[19],
         BotX2[20]+X2[20]]
BotX4 = [BotX3[0]+X3[0],BotX3[1]+X3[1],BotX3[2]+X3[2],BotX3[3]+X3[3],BotX3[4]+X3[4],
         BotX3[5]+X3[5],BotX3[6]+X3[6],BotX3[7]+X3[7],BotX3[8]+X3[8],BotX3[9]+X3[9],
         BotX3[10]+X3[10],BotX3[11]+X3[11],BotX3[12]+X3[12],BotX3[13]+X3[13],BotX3[14]+X3[14],
         BotX3[15]+X3[15],BotX3[16]+X3[16],BotX3[17]+X3[17],BotX3[18]+X3[18],BotX3[19]+X3[19],
         BotX3[20]+X3[20]]
BotX5 = [BotX4[0]+X4[0],BotX4[1]+X4[1],BotX4[2]+X4[2],BotX4[3]+X4[3],BotX4[4]+X4[4],
         BotX4[5]+X4[5],BotX4[6]+X4[6],BotX4[7]+X4[7],BotX4[8]+X4[8],BotX4[9]+X4[9],
         BotX4[10]+X4[10],BotX4[11]+X4[11],BotX4[12]+X4[12],BotX4[13]+X4[13],BotX4[14]+X4[14],
         BotX4[15]+X4[15],BotX4[16]+X4[16],BotX4[17]+X4[17],BotX4[18]+X4[18],BotX4[19]+X4[19],
         BotX4[20]+X4[20]]
ind = np.arange(N)
width = 0.7
p1 = plt.bar(ind, X,  width, color='r',)
p2 = plt.bar(ind, X1, width, color='y', bottom=X)
p3 = plt.bar(ind, X2, width, color='g', bottom=BotX2)
p4 = plt.bar(ind, X3, width, color='b', bottom=BotX3)
p5 = plt.bar(ind, X4, width, color='c', bottom=BotX4)
p6 = plt.bar(ind, X5, width, color='m', bottom=BotX5)
plt.xticks(ind+width/2., ('L', 'S', 'R', 'G', 'V', "P", "T", "A", "I", "F", "Y", "H", 
                          "Q", "N", "K", "D", "E", "C", "W", "STOP", "M" ) )




plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the [`position`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html?highlight=set%20x%20labels#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels) keyword?

```
plt.xticks(ind+width/2., 
           ('L', 'S', 'R', 'G', 'V', "P", "T", "A", "I", "F", "Y", "H", 
            "Q", "N", "K", "D", "E", "C", "W", "STOP", "M" ), 
           position=(0, 0.5))
```

That should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response.
It's probably my fault for not being clear enough.
I'll show you what I get: http://i.imgur.com/Tnlu5uH.jpg?1
I've photshopped what I want to achieve: http://i.imgur.com/E6KuGze.jpg?1
Sorry for not being clear enough.

Comment: Does `position` keyword do what you want?